# What numbers (e.g. 0, -1, or 1.0) are plurals in Latin?

Tags: grammar-choice, contemporary-latin, new-latin, numbers

The basic question is: With which numbers should I use a plural form of the noun?

#### Background: English

In English it seems to me that the only singular number is 1 (and maybe -1), but everything else is plural.
To use the example word "degree", I think the most idiomatic thing to say is:

> 1 degree
> -1 degree(s)
> 2 degrees
> 1.0 degrees
> -1.0 degrees
> 0 degrees
> -3 degrees
> 1.5 degrees
> 2.1 degrees

I am not sure whether -1 is more naturally plural or singular.
Some of the things are obvious, but it is less obvious (but in my experience true) that 0 and 1.0 (which is not<sup>1</sup> quite the same thing as 1) are treated as plural.

Finnish does the same as English here.
I do not know other modern languages well enough to tell whether this is typical.

#### Question: Latin

Which numbers make a noun go plural in Latin?
For the most common numbers (1, 2, 3, …) this is trivial.
But how about the other things, like 0, -1, and 1.0?
I assume decimal numbers<sup>2</sup> like 2.3 are plural, but the ones I listed above are less obvious.

I assume this does not come up in classical Latin, but I think this is inevitable during the rise of science around the 18th century.
A significant amount of scientific literature that would use numbers like this is in Latin, so I think that an answer to this question must have existed in practice.

##### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>
The difference between 1 and 1.0 can be seen in different ways.
Sometimes 1.0 means that this is a numerical value with possibly some error in it.
The number 1 is always an exact and absolute number, and no measurement or numerical calculation will ever give it as a result.
In some programming languages there is a type difference so that 1 is an integer and 1.0 is a floating point number, and they are treated differently.
I don't want to go into unnecessary detail here, but this should suffice to convince the reader of the difference for the purposes of this question.

<sup>2</sup>
How to pronounce decimal numbers like 2.3 in Latin is a good and related question.
If you want to discuss that, I recommend that you ask a separate question.